# period in jQuery function parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, webforms

What is the purpose of the period in front
of the answer in parameter of the following 
code?:

```
$jq(".answer-status").click( function() {
```

more complete:

```
$jq =jQuery.noConflict();
$jq(document).ready( function() {
  $jq(".answer-status").click( function() {
    var answer_button = $jq(this);
    var answer_status  = $jq(this).attr("data-ques-status");
```

thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _period_?

Comment: @Vohuman — `.` aka full stop.

Comment: try reading the docs about how jQuery works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery accepts [a string containing a selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) as one of the forms of argument to its core function.

jQuery selector syntax is [documented in the manual](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and is based on [W3C selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

A selector starting with a `.` character is a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

It selects elements that are members of [an HTML class](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes) such as `<p class="answer-status">`.